# Losing the this scope with an event listener

Tags: javascript

So I have a class declaration and in my constructor I want to add an event listener when the window scrolls. Something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(el, options) {
        // (...) initiating this properties and methods
        $window.on('scroll', this.onScroll);
    }
```

When I add my event listener I lose the `this` scope (onScroll() creates its own `this` instance), but if I use `$window.on('scroll', () => this.scroll());` I keep my `this` scope. Is there a way to keep my scope and not using the arrow function?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Function#bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It returns the function attached to the given context.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(el, options) {
        $window.on('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like below:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(el, options) {        
        $window.on('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Or just modify the way you define onScroll function:

```
this.onScroll = () => { ... }
```