# TypeError on property of class even though I've defined it in the constructor

Tags: javascript, class, dom

I have the following JavaScript class representing an HTML element. It is part of a quiz program, and consists of a text input where a user enters their answer, a button to mark their answer (check whether or not it is correct) and a bit of text which, after marking, shows whether it is correct or not.

The class constructor is:

```
    constructor(correctAnswer) {
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        
        this.rootHTMLElement = document.createElement("div");

        this.textInputElement = document.createElement("input");
        this.textInputElement.type = "text";
        this.rootHTMLElement.appendChild(this.textInputElement);

        this.statusIndicatorElement = document.createElement("span");
        this.rootHTMLElement.appendChild(this.statusIndicatorElement);

        this.button = document.createElement("button");
        this.button.innerText = "Mark";
        this.rootHTMLElement.appendChild(this.button);
        this.button.addEventListener("click", this.markSelf);
    }
```

and the `markSelf` method referenced in the button event listener is

```
    markSelf() {        
        switch (this.textInputElement.value) {
            case this.correctAnswer:
                this.statusIndicatorElement.innerText = "Correct";
                break
            case "":
                this.statusIndicatorElement.innerText = "Not marked";
                break
            default:
                this.statusIndicatorElement.innerText = "Incorrect";
                break
        }
    }
```

These are the only two methods that access `this.textInputElement`.

However, clicking the button (which calls the markSelf method) causes `Uncaught TypeError: this.textInputElement is undefined`.

How can I modify this to have the intended behavior (changing the content of `statusIndicatorElement` based on whether the content in the text input matches the correct answer or not)?

Comment: How do you call `markSelf` ? The problem can be that `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: `this.button.addEventListener("click", this.markSelf)` is going to be the problem, because the `markSelf` method will be called by the browser when you click, and it won't use the `this` you expect. There should be plenty of questions here explaining this, I'll try to dig one of them up for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Losing the this scope with an event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236310/losing-the-this-scope-with-an-event-listener) (that question is itself a duplicate but I chose it because the original question more or less exactly mirrors what you've got here - you can read the one it's a duplicate of for more detailed explanations of what's going on)

Comment: @Titus I was calling it by clicking the button which has been associated with it by `this.button.addEventListener` - that indeed turned out to be the problem, as I had assumed wrongly about what `this` does inside an event listener callback.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, this has helped with my problem, thank you.